# javascript JSON data access

Tags: json

Sorry for my english,

I have following JSON literal notation.

```
[
  {
    "ktp_app": [
      "hantong",
      "hantong4",
      "hantong2",
      "hantong3"
    ],
    "ktp_apps":[
      "kun1"
    ]
  }
]
```

I parsed this with eval // var tmp = eval(jsondata);

i could access first array of data which means

```
{"ktp_app":["hantong","hantong4","hantong2","hantong3"],"ktp_apps":["kun1"]}**
```

but after that, how could i access the other part of json data,. only way i could access is to use a

tmp[0]["ktp_app"] ... but i want to access without String., i want use loop so that i can access all of the data;..

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the . operator. So:

```
json = [
  {
    "ktp_app": [
      "hantong",
      "hantong4",
      "hantong2",
      "hantong3"
    ],
    "ktp_apps":[
      "kun1"
    ]
  }
]

json[0].ktp_app[0] would give "hantong".
```

Alternatively you can do it like this:

```
json[0]["ktp_app"][0] would give "hantong"
```

In a loop:

```
for (name in json[0]) {
  var elem = json[0][name]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to loop over the values in you data object:

```
var data = [
  {
    "ktp_app": [
      "hantong",
      "hantong4",
      "hantong2",
      "hantong3"
    ],
    "ktp_apps":[
      "kun1"
    ]
  }
];
for (key in data[0]) { 
  console.log(data[0][key]); 
}
```